# Forms using ajax with no page reload, getting Sessions variables To refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am somewhat new to building web forms without having a series of pages. I have in the past been a PHP programmer, now that I am starting to use some javascript technologies as well such as communicating with my PHP document via AJAX, I am running into a problem.

So I have a series of forms all on one page that is used for making a pizza for an online ordering website. 
The form in general is working and I am able to pull POST data from the forms to store into sessions. My problem is that on the second last form, the user selects the toppings they want on their pizza. 
Then the last form uses those toppings to populate a list that uses a jQuery sortable script so that the user can sort their toppings into the left side, whole, or right side of their pizza.
The problem is that since all these forms are on one page, the page loads the sessions variables right from the original page load and by the time they get set from the user choosing the toppings, they have already been loaded into the page so they don't refresh. So basically when I refresh the page manually by the browser, the jquery sortable form always shows the toppings I choose the LAST time I choose them before refreshing the page.. Basically I need to Update the sessions when the user chooses their toppings and push the updates to the already loaded form.

Here is a code section:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

```
<!--Fourth Pizza Form, Select What Kinds Of Toppings-->                  
<div id="pizzatoppingtypes" >
     <form method="post" name="toppingtypesform" id="toppingtypesformid">   
        <div id="main">
            <div class="example">
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Bacon"/><label style="color:black" for="bacon"><span><span></span></span>Bacon</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Banana Peppers"/><label style="color:black" for="bananapeppers"><span><span></span></span>Banana Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Black Olives"/><label style="color:black" for="blackolives"><span><span></span></span>Black Olives</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Green Peppers"/><label style="color:black" for="greenpeppers"><span><span></span></span>Green Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Ham"/><label style="color:black" for="ham"><span><span></span></span>Ham</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Hamburger"/><label style="color:black" for="hamburger"><span><span></span></span>Hamburger</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Italian Sausage"/><label style="color:black" for="italiansausage"><span><span></span></span>Italian Sausage</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Jalapeno Peppers"/><label style="color:black" for="jalapenopeppers"><span><span></span></span>Jalapeno Peppers</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Canned Mushrooms"/><label style="color:black" for="cannedmushrooms"><span><span></span></span>Canned Mushrooms</label>
              </div>             
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Fresh Mushrooms"/><label style="color:black" for="freshmushrooms"><span><span></span></span>Fresh Mushrooms</label>
              </div>        
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Onions"/><label style="color:black" for="onions"><span><span></span></span>Onions</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Pepperoni"/><label style="color:black" for="pepperoni"><span><span></span></span>Pepperoni</label>
              </div>    
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Pineapple"/><label style="color:black" for="pineapple"><span><span></span></span>Pineapple</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Sliced Smoked Sausage"/><label style="color:black" for="slicedsmokedsausage"><span><span></span></span>Sliced Smoked Sausage</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input id="toppingtypes" type="checkbox" name="toppingtypes" value="Extra Cheese"/><label style="color:black" for="extracheese"><span><span></span></span>Extra Cheese</label>
              </div>              
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>    
</div>
<div><button href="#" id="btn4">Sort Pizza Toppings</button></div>  

<!--Fifth Pizza Form, Sort The Toppings-->    
<div id="pizzatoppingsort" >
            <form method="post" name="splittoppings" id="splittoppingsid    
                <div id="main">
                    <div class="example">
                        <div>
                            <!--The First Half (Left Side) Of The Pizza-->
                            <div id="pos" width="200px">
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhierholzer/onlineordering/master/images/pizzaleft.gif"/>
                                <h3>First Half</h3>
                                    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                                      <!--The Potential Moved Items Go Here-->
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!--The Whole Pizza-->  
                            <div id="pos" style="margin-left:200px;" width="200px">
                                <img align="center" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhierholzer/onlineordering/master/images/pizza.gif"/>
                                <h3>Whole Pizza</h3>
                                    <ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
                                    <?php 

                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][0])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][0] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][1])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][1] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][2])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][2] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][3])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][3] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][4])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][4] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][5])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][5] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][6])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][6] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][7])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][7] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][8])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][8] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][9])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][9] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][10])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][10] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][11])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][11] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][12])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][12] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';}
                                      if(isset($_SESSION["selectedarray"][13])) {echo '<li class="ui-state-default">' . $_SESSION["selectedarray"][13] . '</li>';} else {echo ' ';} 
                                    ?>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>  
                            <!--The Second Half (Right Side) Of The Pizza-->    
                            <div id="pos" style="margin-left:400px;" width="200px">
                                <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhierholzer/onlineordering/master/images/pizzaright.gif"/>
                                <h3>Second Half</h3> 
                                    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                                      <!--The Potential Moved Items Go Here-->
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
</div>
<!--Add Pizza Item To Cart-->
<div style="margin-left:600px;"><button href="#" id="btn5">Add Pizza To Cart</button></div> 


<!--Javascript:-->


$('#btn4').click(function(e){   
var selected = new Array();
$("input:checkbox[name=toppingtypes]:checked").each(function()
    {
               selected.push($(this).val());
             $.post("toppingtypes.php",
            {
              selectedarray: selected,
            },
            function(data,status){
            });
    });
  // alert(selected); (Was Used To Test Value)

    $('#pizzatoppingtypes, #btn4').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#pizzatoppingsort, #btn5').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#toppingtypesformid').submit();      
    });
});


<!--PHP: (In a different location) (toppingtypes.php)-->


<?php
session_start();
$selectedarray = $_POST["selectedarray"];
$_SESSION['selectedarray'] = $selectedarray;
echo "." . $_SESSION["selectedarray"] . ".";
?>
```

Here is a location To my GitHub Repositiry if you would like to look at all the code for this pizza ordering section (I stripped all the CSS and Visuals out of it to make it easier to troubleshoot)
https://github.com/dhierholzer/Basiconlineordering

Thanks again so much for any help at all!

Comment: I don't got it.
Do you have a status area to show toppings in your html and you want to show the changes of it in this area?

Comment: You choose what toppings you want, and then when you hit next, i want those toppings that were just selected to populate a list. and on this list the user can separate the toppings according to what side of the pizza they want them on.. Right now, it works but the sorting is always one refresh behnd. For instance, if I choose 2 toppings (pepperoni, and mushrooms) and then hit next. Then I hit refresh on the broswer and go through all the forms again and this time choose 3 toppings, (onions, pepper, and pepperoni),

Comment: When I get to the sorting list, it will be populated with 2 toppings (pepperoni and mushroom) becauase those were the toppings in place when I hit refresh on the broswer so the page loaeded those items for the list before I got around to the topping choosing form again. So I need to find a way to update the sessions to the forms and have it load upon completion of choosing the toppings NOT at the beginning of the page. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm creating an example and after that, i will show it to you